# omitir los duplicados de registros en un join

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

tengo el siguiente sql sintaxis para realizar la consulta de 2 tablas:

```
declare
@var_almacen char(10) = 'LM01',
@var_periodo char(6) = '202211'

select 
distinct lk.Item,lmp.CodigoInterno,lmp.DescripcionCompleta,lk.Fecha,lk.ReferenciaTipoDocumento,
lk.ReferenciaNumeroDocumento,lk.Cantidad,sum(lk.Cantidad)
from LG_Kardex lk
inner join LG_MaestroProductos lmp on lk.Item = lmp.Item
where lmp.Estado = 'A' and AlmacenCodigo = @var_almacen and Periodo = @var_periodo
group by lk.Item,lmp.CodigoInterno,lmp.DescripcionCompleta,lk.Fecha,lk.ReferenciaTipoDocumento,lk.ReferenciaNumeroDocumento,lk.Cantidad
HAVING COUNT(lk.Item) > 0
order by lk.Item
```

el cual da como resultado los siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el cual como se puede ver me sale con todo los duplicados de la columna Item, y eso no puedo hacer que solo salga un solo registro, incluso intente usando sum en la columna Cantidad y aun asi no logro el objetivo que salga sin registros duplicados.

Comment: Y si queres que salga una sola fila, que datos tienen que aparecer en todas las otras columnas que son distintas?

Comment: quiero que salga todas las columnas evitando los duplicados de la columna Item

Comment: no te entiendo, para el item 00001, que datos queres que salgan en las otras columnas?? NI o NS? y porque cual es el concepto para las otras columnas?

Comment: si le parece mejor quitemos las columnas ReferenciaTipoDocumento y ReferenciaNumeroDocumento para que sea mas entendible lo que se necesita

Comment: Y la columna fecha? y la columna cantidad??? no entiendo que queres mostrar en todas esas.. y si pones un ejemplo de que salida queres?

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes, es muy simple de ver.

[image: res1]

Las columnas `Item, CodigoInterno, Descripcion`, para el `item=00001` se podrían reducir a una sola fila, que es lo que pareces querer.

Pero no le estás indicando que hacer con la columna `fecha`. Esta tiene dos valores diferentes. Para reducir a una sola fila ese item, ¿Cuál se queda?

- La fecha menor.
- La fecha mayor.
- Otra ocurrencia cualquiera.
- ....

Si seguimos por las columnas siguientes a la derecha ocurre lo mismo.

Para que tengamos una sola fila del `item 00001`, que valor dejamos para `ReferenciaTipoDocumento`.

En definitivas cuentas, lo que estás pidiendo en la sentencia, te lo está haciendo perfectamente, porque te ha agrupado y aplicado distinct a todas las filas que tienen valores diferentes.

Lo que supongo quieres es:

```
declare @Var_almacen char(10) = 'LM01'
      , @Var_periodo char(6)  = '202211';

select lk.Item
     , lmp.CodigoInterno
     , lmp.DescripcionCompleta
     , MAX(lk.Fecha) -- PARA TENER DISTINTOS HACE FALTA QUE SOLO HAYA UN RESULTADO.
     , MAX(lk.ReferenciaTipoDocumento)
     , MAX(lk.ReferenciaNumeroDocumento)
     , MIN(lk.Cantidad)
     , Sum(lk.Cantidad)
       from LG_Kardex AS lk
            inner join LG_MaestroProductos AS lmp on lk.Item = lmp.Item
       where
            lmp.Estado = 'A' and AlmacenCodigo = @Var_almacen and Periodo = @Var_periodo
       group by lk.Item
              , lmp.CodigoInterno
              , lmp.DescripcionCompleta
       HAVING Count(lk.Item) > 0
       order by lk.Item;
```

Si observas la consulta, contra la que tú has expuesto, las columnas que tienen datos que muestran valores diferentes para el item, las he metido dentro de una función de agrupación. Y esto implica que las he sacado de Group By.

Pero ojo, yo he escogido esas funciones, que puede que no sean las que tú quieras.

Por otro lado al haber agrupado, ya no es necesario distinct.

Hay un montón de funciones de agregado, que cada una, como es lógico hace algo diferente.

Tendrás que pensar cuales quieres usar, o al menos que resultado esperas obtener.

[Sql server funciones de agregado](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)